# Html files running on vscode live server but not on flask

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am creating a dashboard with multiple html files and I can run them ok on vscode live-server, when I try to run lets say the index file from an app.py file on flask. It does not work. This is some of the code. Can anyone give any insight on why this may be the case?

index file

```
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- The header starts here -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
                    <a class="navbar-brand h1 goofy_blue" href="./index.html">
                        <h1>Renewable Energy</h1>
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ul_format" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Plots
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="solar.html">
                                            solar
                                            <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
                                        </a>
```

app.py

```
#################################################
# Flask Setup
#################################################
app = Flask(__name__)


#################################################
# Flask Routes
#################################################


@app.route("/")
def welcome():
    """Return the homepage."""
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: The HTML you provided seems to be incomplete. Also, I am not sure I fully understand your question. Is it that you are able to open the HTML file in the browser but not serve it through Flask? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: This is the main part of it, I can run the solar.html file from the index html file, but I cannot serve it through flask via the index.html, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your HTML files are in templates/ within your Flask app folder

Answer (score 0):

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
```

Make sure to assign template folder in app = Flask() and put all HTML files in that Folder